# Why i cant check if a variable have a value using == true?

Tags: c++, c

`if(10)` it is true, but `if(10 == true)` is false. Can someone tell me why the first case convert the number to bool but the second case didnt?

Comment: try `if(!!10 == true)`

Comment: the value of 'true' can be anything (I have often seen 1 and !0 and 2 in various compilers.   However, anything that is not 0 (false) can be tested and the test will return 'true'.  That is why you can use: `if(10)` but not `if( 1== true)`    In the 'if' statement that fails, the value 1 is being compared to value being used to represent 'true'.  In any case, 10 is not 1 (nor 2 nor !0)  so the result of the comparison is false.

Comment: @user3629249: In c++, `true` is a boolean value which will be converted precisely to 1 if promoted to an integer. I believe that is consistent with c99, given the inclusion of `stdbool.h`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`if (10)` is equivalent to `if (10 != 0)`, whereas `if (10 == true)` is  `if (10 == 1)` (since `true` is promoted to the value `1` of type `int`).

In layman's terms: Two things that both happen to satisfy some property aren't automatically the same thing.

(E.g. doughnuts and frisbees are both round, but that doesn't mean a doughnut is equal to a frisbee. Integers and booleans can both be evaluated in a boolean context, but that doesn't mean that every integer that evaluates as true is equal to every true boolean.)

Comment: I am not sure if your laymen terms are really laymen. I find them arcane! :)

Comment: What's wrong with people on Stackoverflow? `if( 10 )` is NOT equivalent to `if( 10 != 0 )`. They are probably equivalent to each other after compiler optimization. You may say that they have the same consequences / outcomes / side effects but they are not equivalent statements.

Comment: @lllllllllll But it is isn't it? Doesn't the expression in C evaluates to true if the it is non-zero?

Comment: @lllllllllll the C standard 6.8.4.1.2 says of `if` statements: "In both forms, the first substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0". I understand that that technically there's a difference (since they are _literally_ not the same program, and in `if(10 != 0)` the body is executed if the expression `10!=0` compares unequal to 0), it's helpful in understanding to see it written out in C.

Comment: `if( 10 )` executes `if` statement "directly" in `C`. In `C++`, it becomes `if( true )`. However, `if( 10 != 0 )` becomes `if( 1 )` in `C` (not `if( 10 )`) or `if( true )` in `C++`. A compiler needs to optimize `10 != 0`  to `1` or `true`. A compiler parses  and evaluates **binary** expression `10 != 0`

Comment: @SergeyA: It's like this: Have you been to China? No? Then you must know my sister - she has also never been to China.

Comment: Since we're on the subject of types and promotions: note that in C and C++ the expression `10 == 1` has slightly different semantics: In C++ the expression has type `bool`, whereas in C it has type `int` and takes values `0` or `1`. (C didn't have a boolean type until recently.)

Answer (score 1):

```
if( ... )
{
     // if statement
}
```

To execute `if` statement in C++, `...` should have a `true` value.

When you wrote `if( 10 ){//something useful}`

I think `10` treats as `int` but not `bool` variable. The following logic should be applied then

```
if( 10 ) -> if( bool( 10 ) ) -> if( true )
```

When you write `if( 10 == true ){//something useful}`, according to C++ standard, there should be the following logic behind the scene

```
if( 10 == true ) -> if( 10 == int( true ) ) -> if( 10 == 1 ) -> if( false )
```

You may write something like

```
if( 10 != false )
```

or

```
if( !!10 == true )
```

also

```
if( ( bool ) 10 == true ) // alternatively, if( bool ( 10 ) == true )
```

---

In old `C` (before `C99`), there is no `false` or `true`, but there are 0 or non-0 values.

In modern `C` (from `C99`), there is `false` or `true` (`<stdbool.h>`), but they are syntactic sugar for `0` and `1`, respectively.

```
if( 10 ) // evaluates directly since 10 is non-zero value

if( 10 == true ) -> if( 10 == 1 ) -> if( 0 )
```

Comment: "true is a syntactic sugar for 1 of type bool" Huh? This is not correct. `true` is not syntactic sugar. Turning `10 == true` into `10 == bool(1)` is going the wrong direction.

Comment: @GManNickG, So what's is `true`? Why I see `1` when I `std::cout << true << std::end`?

Comment: `true` and `false` are keywords, and they are boolean literals. They have the type `bool` (not `int`). A value of type `bool` is defined as either being `true` or `false`. The reason you see `1` there is a behavior of `std::ios_base`; by default, booleans are cast to `int` and outputted (`true` casts to `1`, `false` casts to `0`). You can change this behavior with [`std::boolalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha).

Comment: @GManNickG What's is a `keyword` then? What I meant by my answer that `true` is syntactic sugar of 1-bit binary representation of 1 ( `bool( 1 )` or `0b1`).

Comment: Please read the standard if you want to know the details of the language; a `keyword` is a syntactic construct of parsing. Also, booleans are *not* a single bit; they are at least 1 byte, because all types have `sizeof(T) >= 1`, including `bool`.

Comment: @GManNickG When I type 0 or 1 in any C++ program, what g++ compiler see? Is it the same as 0b0 or 0b1, false or true or something else?

Comment: @GManNickG Does `true` or `false` is syntactic sugar of 8-bit representation of `1` or `0` respectively?

Comment: "4.12. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false;" So, yes I was wrong. 0 is converted to false but not other way around.

Comment: `0` and `1` are integer literals, and will have type `int`. No, `true` and `false` *are not syntactic sugar*, and booleans are not necessarily 8 bits; the size of `bool` is unspecified. However the compiler decides to implement `bool` is up to the compiler, bits are totally unknown as far as we're concerned.

Comment: @GManNickG

`true` and `false` are not syntactic sugar in C++ (I was wrong);
`true` and `false` are syntactic sugar in C (from C99)

Answer (score -1):

Because they are entirely different things.

In C, anything that is NOT false is automatically true, and C has a very strict definition of `false`.

You can think of `if(10)` as `if(10 != false)`

and likewise `if (10 == true)` as `if((10 == true) != false)`

Answer (score -2):

`10` is clearly not `true`, in the sense that `10` is a number and `true` is a `boolean`.

When you're in an if statement, the compiler has to evaluate the condition until it reaches either a true or a false. If it does not reach a true or a false, it has to convert it to a true or a false. As a general rule, `0` evaluates to false, and everything else evaluates to true.

So `if(-1)` is true, as is `if(234)` and so on.

The expression `10 == true` already evaluates to false, so no further conversion is needed. `if(10)` is neither true or false, so the compiler has to convert it, using our rule above, and it becomes true.

Comment: Wrong reasoning in the beginning `1 == true` is true, even though `1` is a number is an `int` constant, and `true` is a `bool` constant.

Comment: It's a bit more complex than that, and also different in C and C++. In C++, the controlling expression of the `if` statement is *contextually converted to `bool`".  In C, the controlling expressions is compared for equality with 0.

Comment: Ah and in C, the `true` and `false` are macros, that expand to `1` and `0`, which are just like another integer constant.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications!